# Log4j2 SyslogAppender TCP to syslog-ng

Tags: log4j2, syslog-ng

I want to use log4j2 to send my log messages to an syslog server(syslog-ng in my case).
I have two issues right now

If I stop the syslog service, and start my application it says

```
2015-04-22 09:56:14,582 ERROR TcpSocketManager (TCP:192.168.0.81:1000)   java.net.ConnectException:
```

And from then on, my application hangs, until a Exception is thrown and my application crashes.

```
2015-04-22 09:59:21,064 ERROR Unable to write to stream TCP:192.168.0.81:1000 for appender RFC5424
```

What I want is that log4j tries to send the logmessage, and If the server is not available it should buffer it, until the server is available again(is this possible at all?, I thought immediateFail=false should do it) Which comes to my second problem.

If I start my application (with syslog-ng available) and then I stop it after a while and start it again. It get not reconnected(EDIT: Ok It does after a while, but lost a lot of logmessages).

Here is my log42.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyAppx" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n" />
    </Console>
    <Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="192.168.0.81" port="1000"
    protocol="TCP" appName="app" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
    facility="LOCAL0" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" immediateFail="false"
    messageId="Audit" id="App" ignoreExceptions="true"/>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RFC5424" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I am open for other solutions, but what I want is that no logmessage is lost at all. And sooner or later all logmessages should be available on an central stations(thats because I wanna use a syslogserver instead of multiple local files)